# Conditional questioning and multiple questioning strains in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to develop a method of questioning in excel (VBA). The questioning will be conditional on the previous answer either carrying on on a question set strain or if a no comes up heading to the next question set strain. at the end if each strain, if reached, id like to save the answers and aggregate them all at the end.

I would try to put some code that I have started, but i have no idea how to do this and not even sure it's possible.

I have added a picture of how I envisage the logic to go.

If anyone can help that would be amazing!

Many thanks
[image]

Comment: it seems like the image add doesn't work.

Comment: can you add your code, and an example of how the question text is laid out.

Answer (score 0):

To give you something to start with, try this:

```
Sub Questions()
Dim Answers() As String, strTemp As String
Dim SetCount As Integer, QCount As Integer

SetCount = 3 'Question Sets
QCount = 4 'Max Number of Question

ReDim Answers(SetCount, QCount) 'Stores Answers

For i = 1 To SetCount 'Loop trough Sets
    For j = 1 To QCount 'Loop trough Question
        Answers(i, j) = Message(Q(i & j), i) 'Message Returns Answers of Set i and Question j
        If Answers(i, j) = "" Or Answers(i, j) = "No" Then 'Exit if no more Question or "No"
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
Next i

'Output
For i = 1 To SetCount
strTemp = strTemp & "Set" & i & ":" & vbNewLine
    For j = 1 To QCount
        strTemp = strTemp & vbTab & "Question " & j & ":" & Answers(i, j) & vbNewLine
    Next j
strTemp = strTemp & vbNewLine
Next i

MsgBox (strTemp) 'Print Answers
End Sub

Function Message(ByVal Question As String, ByVal Title As String) As String
If Question <> "Nothing" Then 'Valid Answers
    If MsgBox(Question, vbYesNo, Title) = vbYes Then
        Message = "Yes"
    Else
        Message = "No"
    End If
Else
    Message = "" 'No more Questions
End If
End Function

Function Q(ByVal Question As Integer) As String
'Stores Questions
Select Case Question
    Case 11: Q = "Set 1 Question 1"
    Case 12: Q = "Set 1 Question 2"
    Case 13: Q = "Set 1 Question 3"
    Case 21: Q = "Set 2 Question 1"
    Case 22: Q = "Set 2 Question 2"
    Case 23: Q = "Set 2 Question 3"
    Case 24: Q = "Set 2 Question 4"
    Case 31: Q = "Set 3 Question 1"
    Case 32: Q = "Set 3 Question 2"
    Case Else: Q = "Nothing"
End Select
End Function
```

Questions are stored in the function `Q`. It will continue with the same set on a "Yes" and jumps to the next set on a "No". `SetCount` and `QCount` have to be adjusted when adding new questions/sets.